# Why parameterize systems of equations that contain "free variables"?

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations, parametrization

As an example, let's say you have the system of equations given by

$$x+y+z = 1$$

$$2x+2y+2z = 2$$

$$3x+3y+3z=3$$

As the first few steps, we recognize that solutions to the first equation are solutions to all of them, so we parameterize the first, for instance by writing

$$x=r$$

$$y=s$$

$$z = 1-r-s$$

Point being to show that we can insert arbitrary values into the parameters $r, s$, and produce a $z$ which gives us a guaranteed solution to the system above.

**Question**

Why go through the step of parameterizing the "free variables"? It always seemed like a redundant step to me. I've perused at least 7 Linear Algebra books hoping that one would give a reason, but they all just tell us to do it.

Comment: Your solution set for the above system can be written as $\left\{r(1,0,-1)+s(0,1,-1)+(0,0,1)~:~r,s\in\Bbb R\right\}$

Comment: @JMoravitz - That's actually quite nice. Is that the general motivation for using them? Can't I write the same but replacing the parameters with their original variable names?

Comment: I mean... you can use whatever names you like for the parameters as you want, however by using the name "$x$" a reader might incorrectly interpret this as having some special significance in relation to the $x$ coordinate which there might not be.  You could just as well write the solution set for the above system as $\{r(-7,4,3)+s(2,2,-4)+(0.5,0.5,0)~:~r,s\in\Bbb R\}$.  Of course the first way of writing it was much cleaner, we like having $1$'s and $0$'s where possible, but this second way of writing it highlights how $r$ doesn't necessarily need to be tied to the $x$ coordinate in any way.

Comment: @JMoravitz - The thing about not assigning the wrong geometrical intuition to the $x$-value is a really good point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parametrizing a space with coordinates from a know space gives you a more concrete description of the solution space. It can tell you the dimension of the solution space, it can give you explicit descriptions of what the solutions look like, and it can facilitate checking whether a given point is a solution or not.

In this particular case there is indeed no need to introduce new variables $r$ and $s$. You can simply parametrize the space of all solutions $V$ as $(x,y,1-x-y)$ with $x,y\in\Bbb{R}$. But introducing these new variables comes from the view that the parametrization is in fact a bijection
$$f:\ \Bbb{R}^2\ \longrightarrow\ V:\ (r,s)\ \longrightarrow\ (r,s,1-r-s).$$
From this point of view the parameters $r$ and $s$ are coordinates in a new space, the parametrizing space $\Bbb{R}^2$, and hence they get new names.

Now it turns out that for systems of *linear* equations over a field you can always choose a parametrization in terms of the coordinate functions (here in terms of $x$ and $y$). In this case these new parameter names seem redundant (and perhaps they are?). But outside the scope of linear algebra these are not at all redundant. For example, it is impossible to parametrize the rational points on the circle in terms of any of its coordinates; here it is necessary to introduce a new parameter.

Comment: I really like the idea of the bijection you mention; having a function that maps one point in the $r,s$ plane to a unique point on the solution space. As you mention, there's really no difference between an $r,s$ plane, and an $x,y$ plane here, but you mention that at some point this is not true. I ask from pure curiosity; what kind of math course or mathematical field are we looking at where the parametrizing space is different from the space of the variables the parameters come from? I don't think I'd understand the details even if you explained them, but it would be nice to know the name.

Comment: @Alec My last sentence suggests such an example; another perhaps more familiar example is given by the circle in $\Bbb{R}^2$ itself. The points on the circle cannot be parametrized as$(x,f(x))$ with $x\in\Bbb{R}$ for any function $f$. But every point is of the form $(\cos(t),\sin(t))$ for some unique $t\in[0,2\pi)$.

Comment: @Alec Upon rereading your comment; the parametrizing space *is* the space of the variables that the parameters come from (in your example $\Bbb{R}^2$). Did you mean the *parametrized* space? (In your example the subspace $V\subset\Bbb{R}^3$).

Comment: Ah, perfect example! I was expecting that examples were far away on the horizon in some "non-linear algebra" course, but there are plenty of examples just a couple steps back.

Comment: Sorry. I meant the space spanned by the two parameters, rather than the two variables.

Answer (score 2):

You would do it to emphasize that this is a parametrization, even if most of the assignments are trivial. It's a shorthand for saying that you have established a correspondence $:\mathbb R^3 \to \mathbb R^3$ defined by 
$(r,s,t) \mapsto (x,y,z)=(r,s,1-r-s)$. Depending on the context, this can make things clearer, it can be unnecessary, or it can complicate things.

Answer (score -2):

The set $\{(x,y,z)\in \Bbb R^3 \; : x+y+z=1\}$ is a plane whose cartesian equation is $x+y+z=1$ and whose parametric equations are
$x=x, y=y, z=1-x-y$

or

$x=a, y=b, z=1-a-b$.

The parametric equations give the two vectors director of the plane.
in your case, the vectors are
$$u=(1,0,-1) \text{ and } v=(0,1,-1)$$

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I understand what the parameters are. What I'm asking is what the motivation is for introducing them, rather than just leaving the variables as they are.